# Normal between coordinate axis

Tags: differential-geometry

Prove that the segment of the normal to the curve 
$$x = 2a \sin t + a \sin t \cos^2t ;\quad y =  a \cos^3t$$ 
contained between the co-ordinate axes is equal to $2a$.

I thought of doing differentiation and proceeding.

But by doing this is getting too long . Is there any good method?

Comment: I can't think of any theorem in differential geometry that instantly answers this, I would just directly answer it as it is. It is just calculus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint...the expression for the gradient of the normal at point $t$ simplifies to $$\cot t$$

Then proceed as usual